# Highlighting a table rows cell based on a thymeleaf value

Tags: html-table, thymeleaf

I need to highlight a cell (Team name) in a table row depending on the cells value.

The closest I have gotten to achieving this is:

[image]

This is not viable as it excludes all the other entities names, adding their position under the "Name" column instead.

Here is my code:

```
<table class = "table">
  <tr>
   <td><h5>Name</h5></td>
   <td><h5>Position</h5></td>
   <td><h5>Played</h5></td>
   <td><h5>Won</h5></td>
   <td><h5>Draw</h5></td>
   <td><h5>Lost</h5></td>
   <td><h5>Points For</h5></td>
   <td><h5>Points Against</h5></td>
   <td><h5>Points Difference</h5></td>
   <td><h5>Winning Bonus Points</h5></td>
   <td><h5>Losing Bonus Points</h5></td>
   <td><h5>Points</h5></td>

  </tr>
   <tr th:each="league : ${league}" >

 <td bgcolor="#FF0000" th:unless="${!#strings.startsWith(league?.name, myteam?.teamName) }"><text th:text="${league?.name}" /></td>
 <td> <text th:text="${league?.pos}" /></td>
 <td> <text th:text="${league?.played}" /></td>
 <td> <text th:text="${league?.won}" /></td>
 <td> <text th:text="${league?.drew}" /></td>
 <td> <text th:text="${league?.lost}" /></td>
 <td> <text th:text="${league?.pointsFor}" /></td>
 <td>  <text th:text="${league?.pointsAgainst}" /></td>
  <td> <text th:text="${league?.pointsDifference}" /></td>
  <td>  <text th:text="${league?.Tb}" /></td>
  <td> <text th:text="${league?.lb}" /></td>
  <td> <text th:text="${league?.pts}" /></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

You can see I am using

```
th:unless="${!#strings.startsWith(league?.name, myteam?.teamName) }"
```

Which is working correctly as it does highlight the appropriate teams name.

K x

Comment: Try using <th th:class="${league.value}? 'even' : 'odd'"></td> or <td th:style="${league.value}?'bgcolor=#FF0000' ? ''"}></td>

Answer (score 0):

You should only use `th:if`/`th:unless` if you want to show or hide elements.  If you don't want that, you should be using other attributes like `th:class`, `th:classappend`, or `th:style`.

Also, you don't need those extra `<text />` tags.  You can put th:text directly on the `<td />` tags.  Here's how it should look:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .my-team {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>

.
.
.

<tr th:each="league : ${league}" th:classappend="${#strings.startsWith(league?.name, myteam?.teamName)}? 'my-team'">
    <td th:text="${league?.name}" />
    <td th:text="${league?.pos}" />
    <td th:text="${league?.played}" />
    <td th:text="${league?.won}" />
    <td th:text="${league?.drew}" />
    <td th:text="${league?.lost}" />
    <td th:text="${league?.pointsFor}" />
    <td th:text="${league?.pointsAgainst}" />
    <td th:text="${league?.pointsDifference}" />
    <td th:text="${league?.Tb}" />
    <td th:text="${league?.lb}" />
    <td th:text="${league?.pts}" />
</tr>
```

Comment: I see! Your explanation has made if clearer for me to understand! Go raibh maith agat.